# PHP 8.0 PHP.ini syntax for session_set_cookie_params

Tags: php

I'm configuring the php.ini file, trying to understand the proper syntax for the php.ini file and setting the session-set-cookie.params. First, it's not clear if the settings needs to be in quotes? Can someone please provide an example for proper syntax? My goal is I want to have session variables available across all sub-domains on my website. It also says, "...you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called." So basically, I need to

```
<?php 
session_set_cookie_params()
session_start()
// PHP CODE HERE

?>
```

Right? Here's the webpage and php.ini code below what I've figured out thus far.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php.

```
session_set_cookie_params(
        int $lifetime_or_options,
        string|null $path = null,
        string|null $domain = null,
        bool|null $secure = null,
        bool|null $httponly = null
    ): bool
```

Here's my config file thus far.

```
 session_set_cookie_params(
    600 $lifetime_or_options,
    $path = .mywebsite.com,
    $domain = /,
    $secure = null,
    $httponly = null
): bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not attempting to modify php.ini here (php.ini is a static server-wide config file loaded before PHP),  but rather set PHP's ini values at runtime via PHP code.  To that end, I think you're just misreading the function definition in the documentation a bit, as to how parameters are expressed.

In later versions of PHP (you're using 8 so that counts), it is best to pass the parameters as an array. This is as listed under *Alternative signature available as of PHP 7.3.0* in the docs. When the docs mention the value `$lifetime_or_options`, they mean that parameter can either be an integer lifetime value (600) or an *array* of all the options as:

Bundle them in an array with `[]`:

```
session_set_cookie_params([
  'lifetime' => 600,
  'path' => '/',
  'domain' => '.yoursite.example.com',
  'secure' => true,
  'httponly' => true
]);
```

Note that I have set `secure` and `httponly` to true. `httponly` will prevent javascript from gaining access to the session cookie, which is appropriate most of the time. However, set `secure` to false if you need your session to work *without* SSL - when set true as I have it, the session cookie would only be transmitted over https.

I have also switched your `path` and `domain` values.

The other older way to express this is just to pass individual values directly as function parameters - that is the part I think you misunderstood in the docs.

```
session_set_cookie_params(600, '/', '.yoursite.example.com', true, true);
```

Note also that 600 is a very short lifetime for a session cookie, only ten minutes. You might need it to live longer.

Comment: THANKS. You were correct, was misreading it, I thought you had to edit the php.ini intrinsically. You edit your php code and insert the session_set_cookie_params BEFORE your session_start() not in the php.ini file! This worked...was so confused over editing the php.ini file, you don't edit it, you leave it alone. Also, what php file(s) you put the session_set_cookie_params in?  Do you need to put it in every php file that uses session data?  I have a sub domain that will access variables...and vice versa. I understand you need to put session_start() but what about session_set_cooke_params?

Comment: @nwood21 Place `session_set_cookie_params()` in every place where you are calling `session_start()`, so every file in your code that expects to access `$_SESSION`. Treat `session_set_cookie_params()` like a modifier to `session_start()` and always call it on the line before `session_start()`.